# JDBC Template: Batch call stored procedure and return result sets

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Java+Spring+Jdbc.

I need to do 100 stored procedure calls using JDBC Template and return merged result sets.

There is an API using batchUpdate(sql, BatchPrepraredStatementSetter) method, however, it will not allow to return result sets, only number of rows updated.

CallableStatement seems to only return one result. Out parameters also did not work for me.

Is this possible using JDBC template?